# PhP to R then PHP

Tags: php

I want to write a php script which takes the data from the database and transfer it into R where data get executed by R qAnalyst package an whatever is the output send it the php script.

Actually the main problem is to plot a interactive plotting rather than static one along with some statistical analysis.

i am actually new to all these things so require experts advise.

Answer (score 0):

I am not the experts but my advise is that you can easily google many related tutorials:

- [PHP Call R](http://www.math.ncu.edu.tw/~chenwc/R_note/index.php?item=php)
- [Executing R in Php](https://www.stanford.edu/~mjockers/cgi-bin/drupal/node/25)
- [The rapache project](http://rapache.net/)
- [Google search results](http://www.google.com.hk/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=umP&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&q=php%20call%20R&btnG=Search&oq=php%20call%20R&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0)